# Difference between BadRequestResult and BadRequestObjectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm going to return a bad request result in my action filter.

I have two choices:

`context.result = new BadRequestResult();`

or

`context.result = new BadRequestObjectResult();`

It seems there are couple types for all status codes: `NotFoundResult` - `NotFoundObjectResult` and so on.

which one I should use and what is differences of these couple types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are for similar purpose, but the second one (`BadRequestObjectResult`) with the difference, an `object` or a `ModelStateDictionary` can be passed as a constructor argument, containing the details regarding the error.

Take a look at the constructors in below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1